# How to ensure js is included in ascx file?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

So the problem is the following :

i do have own user control. which has some javascript file in script tag included like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../somefile.js" ></script>
```

or some javascript code directly on the ascx page.
everything works if i place this control somewhere in aspx markup. but if i add this control to the page dynamically to some UpdatePanel place holder on postback (this is logic i can not alter), control renders itself and then i get js error message, which says that functions which are placed in somefile.js are not defined/are null. Why is this happening ? Is there anyway to force js including in this case.

sorry for being not enough specific but the code amount is huge and i was not able to provide a simplified example with the same error,.

The script is included but somehow the functions are not defined. I'm novice to js, so is it possible that just the script is included but not executed, so the functions are not declared ???

The interesting is that if on some page my custom control is declared in aspx. The adding some more instances dynamically causes no problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the load event of your control, do something like this:

```
if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered("keyName"))
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("keyName",
        Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/MyJavaScript.js"));
```

Answer (score 2):

How about including it in ScriptManager.Scripts like this?

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="scriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/somefile.js" />
        </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Edit:

From ascx you could do something like this (OnPreRender would be where I would try this):

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).Scripts.Add(new ScriptReference("~/somefile.js"));
```

Alternatively, you could try

```
 ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterClientScriptInclude(
            this,
            typeof(Page),
            "UniqueScriptKey",
            ResolveClientUrl("~/somefile.js"));
```

[Reference link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.scripts.aspx)

Comment: can i somehow retrieve it ? it is declared on the master page which i can not modify. i have tried to register the file through ClientScriptManager in the aspx.cs file but it did not work out.

Comment: I have added another method to add Scripts. See Edit.

Comment: Also check out the example in this msdn page. http://msdn.microsoft.com/us-en/library/system.web.ui.scriptreference.aspx

Comment: It would have to be in a ScriptManagerProxy most likely, as there can only be one ScriptManager, and most people put that in the page or master page.

Comment: ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page) gets a reference to the script manager that's available to that page (could be from it's master page). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.getcurrent.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your JS file is loading? It could be that the file is not in the right location - don't use ../ in the path as this is relative and may be wrong if you are sharing this and the pages are not all at the same depth:

do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/somefile.js" ></script>
```

Comment: the JS file is loading if the control is declared in aspx file. i get this problem only if this control is added to some PlaceHolder inside the UpdatePanel dynamically on some postback. I have also tried to include those scripts directly into the ascx file. does not work.